# Intermittent 404 not found error from Nginx

Tags: tomcat, nginx

We are doing a load test on the health page of an application.We are getting intermittent 404 page not found errors as response for some requests. Around 0.03 % of total requests are responding as 404. We checked the Nginx logs and we are getting the below error.

*2017/04/11 11:59:44 [error] 16#0: *18366 open() "/opt/soft/nginx/html/health" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.98.1, server: static.prod.aaaa.dddd.com, request: "GET /health HTTP/1.1", host: "static.prod.aaaaa.dddd.com"*

The health page we are trying to hit is hosted on the upstream tomcat server.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: You should quite certainyl show samples of the configuration. is this just a local static file accessed by Nginx? An Nginx proxy request? And maybe problems occurs when the tool responsible for the static file is re-generating the file?

Comment: From googling the subject I've seen people say they've seen the server get overloaded. You specially mention load test. Maybe see if there's an amount of load you can put on and get no 404 errors and if there's a threshold of load where 404 errors start occurring?